# Jquery Append content from LaravelBalde

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have the following JavaScript code in a laravel blade.

```
<script>
    function banUser(id) {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
                method: "PUT",
                dataType: "json",
                url: '{{URL::route('api.user.update ',['user'=>null])}}/' + id,
                data: {
                    status: "banned",
                }
            })
            .done(function(json) {
                processBanJson(json);
            });
    }

    function unbanUser(id) {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
                method: "PUT",
                url: '{{URL::route('api.user.update ',['user '=>null])}}/' + id,
                data: {
                    status: "registered",
                }
            })
            .done(function(json) {
                processBanJson(json);
            });
    }

    function processBanJson(json) {
        if (json.success) {
            if (json.user.status == "banned") {
                //The user was just banned
                $('#alert-area').append('@include('backend.user._partials.alerts.user-banned')'.trim());
                $('#Ban-User-' + json.user.id + '-btn').hide();
                $('#Unban-User-' + json.user.id + '-btn').show();
            } else {
                //The user is no longer banned
                alert("Unbanned User!");
                $('#alert-area').append();
                $('#Ban-User-' + json.user.id + '-btn').show();
                $('#Unban-User-' + json.user.id + '-btn').hide();
            }
        } else {
            alert("Error Occured");
        }
        $('#User-Status-' + json.user.id).html(json.user.status);
    }
</script>
```

and my ...alerts.user-banned blade contains the following:

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> Alert!</h4>
    <p>User Banned!</p>
</div>
```

After being compiled, the output looks like this:
Sorry,
The issue is, that the rendered HTML looks like this:

```
...
if(json.user.status=="banned")
{
    //The user was just banned
    $('#alert-area').append(('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> Alert!</h4>
<p>User Banned!</p>
</div>').trim());
    $('#Ban-User-'+json.user.id+'-btn').hide();
    $('#Unban-User-'+json.user.id+'-btn').show();
}
...
```

I know that it needs to become all one line, or escaped. But I'm trying to find a clean solution to escape, or minify what is in my alert view so the javascript is valid without having to escape the actual view file itself.

Comment: What is the question? What is the error.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question to include the compiled output.

But, by including the view in such a way it javascript doesn't realize that the string contains multiple lines, and I would prefer not to escape the view file iteself if possible.

So my question is there a way for me to escape/minify just this one include via javascript or through a laravel package I just don't know about/haven't found yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to put this into a package.... But, I think I created a solution;
If someone could verify/improve that would be great!

The following goes into my processBanJson

```
$('#alert-area').append('@oneLine('backend.user._partials.alerts.user-banned')');
```

And while its currently in my routes.php file; A Simple Extend

```
/*
 * Our Custom oneLine Blade Function
 *
 * Imports a blade, and minifies it into one line
 */
Blade::directive('oneLine', function($expression)
{
    return "<?php echo implode(\" \",explode(\"\n\",\$__env->make($expression, array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render())); ?>";
});
```